# Symfony not found psql in PATH

Tags: postgresql, symfony

I'm trying yo start a new Symfony proyect following the guide, but when I run "symfony run psql" i get a error "exec: "psql": executable file not found in %PATH%"

[image: Error]

I tried adding the psql.exe in windows environment variables:

[image: psql path]

But still getting same error

EDIT 1:

I change the environment variable to "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin" and the error has change to:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "app"
command "psql" failed: exit status 2
```

[New error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x7ET.png)

EDIT 2:

config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '15'

    profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
    report_fields_where_declared: true
    validate_xml_mapping: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            type: attribute
            is_bundle: false
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App

when@test:
   doctrine:
       dbal:
            # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
      dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'

when@prod:
    doctrine:
          orm:
              auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
              proxy_dir: '%kernel.build_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
              query_cache_driver:
                  type: pool
                  pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
              result_cache_driver:
                  type: pool
                  pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache. System
```

Edit 3:

```
  DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:app@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=9&charset=utf8"
```

Comment: I think the message is quite clear by itself. `password authentication failed for user "app"` mean that your password is either wrong or not set in your configuration. Assuming you're on Symfony 5.4 or above, can you add the content of `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` to your question ?

Comment: Added, but it's default conf

Comment: Can you also add an example of what is set for `DATABASE_URL` please ?

Comment: There you have ^^

Comment: Xmm... Did you modify `DATABASE_URL` ? Or it's what is currently in your project ? Did you create the user `app` in PostgreSQL and it's database `app` ?